# IntelliJ IDEA: How can I create an breakpoint that debug webpack?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webpack, javascript-debugger

Use Intellij IDEA's debug tool to webpack,

OS:MAC

npm script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": " webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --display-error-details  --content-base   --config mvvm/build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
}
```

it tips:

```
To debug "build-distributor" script, make sure $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION string is specified as the first argument for node command you'd like to debug.

 For example:

{ "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js" }
```

question:

Where to add this code（$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ）？

Answer (score 0):

#### Package.json configuration

First of all you have to create a new Debugging script like this:

```
"debug": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./path/to/webpack.config.js"
```

#### webpack configuration

You have to add this command line:

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map'
```

#### Editor configuration

and then you have to cofigurate your IDE:
[image]
and also this:
[image]